# Number of valid arithmetic equations

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

Given  $?+?-? = 2$

Then the values of ? can be from 1 to 20.

Then from this we can get there can 3 distinct equations can be formed.

But how can we do that for any number of ?.

I am not getting any idea.

Can someone please help me in this.

Comment: Is "?" a symbol meaning the same number ? Id so, you have the equation $x+x-x=2$, i.e. $x=2$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No, these can be different

Comment: Do you mean "$a+b-c=2$" where $\ a,b,c\ $ are integers in then range $[1,201]$ ?

Comment: @Peter Yes like that

Comment: $a+b=c+2$. Thus, with $c=1$ we have $a+b=3$, i.e. two possible solutions : $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$. And so on. It seems $c+1$ solutions for every $c$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yeas like that

Comment: @bhj:  does that let you solve the problem?  Sum it over the acceptable values of $c$.  The rule does not quite hold for $201$ so you need a correction.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry its 20

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Edited the question

Comment: @bhj:  Ok, it was the last one that needed a correction.

Comment: @RossMillikan Will there be a specific formula

Comment: Yes, you need to add up $c+1$ for $c$ from $1$ to $20$.  Have you seen that?